# Get specific array value where another value is "1"?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
    Id = "ADA001"
    Stock: 15
```

The array has about 1700 records that looks the same, how would I search the array for the ID 1 and return the stock?

**Edit:** I will need to access the stock of each one of these 17000 records

**Edit:** I have been getting some help from Daniel Centore, he told me to set an arrays primary key to the id of the item and that it is equal to the stock, but I can't get it to work.

I am currently getting the data from an MySQL database and I store it in an array, like so:

```
       $data[] = array();
    $getdisposabletest = mysqli_query($connect, "Select id, disposable FROM products");      

while ($z = mysqli_fetch_array($getdisposabletest)) {  
    $data = $z;
}
```

Now when I use Daniels code that looks like this:

```
    $myMap = [];
foreach($data as $item) {
    $myMap[$item['id']] = $item['disposable'];
}
```

It doesn't return anything when I try to echo my product with the ID "ADA001"

```
  echo $myMap["ADA001"];
```

Also when I do "count($mymap)" it says its 2 records big, when it should be muuuch larger than that?

Thanks for help

Comment: would you share a little bit more of the array structure

Comment: If the ids are unique then it'll make sense in the long-run for the array to be indexed based on them, as well as solving this particular issue.

Comment: Use `array_filter(...)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php, and if you are sure that the ID's are unique, use `current(array_filter(...))` to return the first record.

Comment: @Anton I forgot that ID is a string actually.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). Return the result of a comparitor.

```
$results = array_filter($targetArray, function($el) {
    return $el === 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Now that it has been made clear that the OP wants to query from thousands of items, the correct way to do this is to make the `Id` the key to a map in PHP, like this:

```
$myMap = [];
foreach($array as $item) {
    $myMap[$item['Id']] = $item['Stock'];
}
```

Now, whenever you want to access item '12', simply use `$myMap['12']`.

The reason this is faster is because of something called algorithmic complexity. You should read about Big-O notation for more info. Essentially, the first operation here is on the order of `n` and then looping through each of the items that comes out is on the order of `n*log(n)`, so the final result is on the order of `n*log(n)` which is the best you'll be able to do without more information. However, if you were only accessing one element, just accessing that one element via MySQL would be better because it would be on the order of `log(n)`, which is faster.

**Edit 2:** Also notice that if you were to access mutliple fields (*ie* not just the stock) you could do the following:

```
$myMap = [];
foreach($array as $item) {
    $myMap[$item['Id']] = $item;
}
```

And simply access item 12's stock like this: `$myMap['12']['stock']` or its name like this: `$myMap['12']['name']`.

Comment: Yes you are correct that I am getting the items from a table, But my system is so much more complex than this and what I am trying to solve right now is just a small part of my system.

Comment: Is this way more efficient still if lets say I have 2000 products and I need to get the stock of each item? Would querying the database over and over again be that efficient?

Comment: No, that would not be more efficient. Make it clear that this is what you want to do in the question and I will update my answer with the correct one.

Comment: This looks good, but how would I go and do it if the id was a string? Is that possible?

Comment: @user2750279 Updated my answer with string keys instead

Comment: I just updated my OP with some issues, could you help me. thanks @Daniel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109061/discussion-between-daniel-centore-and-user2750279).

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this.

```
$newArray=[];
foreach($array as $item){
    if($item['Id'] === 1){
        $newArray[] = $item;
    }
}
$stockArray = array_column($newArray,'Stock');
```

Comment: I would certainly use `===` if testing for 1 or 0.

Comment: I don't know if the 1 is a string or integer

Comment: for an array of 1700 entries I would suggest making the id a key to the array